# setstate vs normal assignment in a stateful widget

Tags: dart, flutter, state, stateful

I am developing a stateful widget and I did not yet understand the difference between useing `setState` and a normal variable assignment.

This is the code I am useing:

```
import ...

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String _state_var;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    setState(() {
      _state_var = "test";
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, AppState>(
      converter: (store) => store.state,
      builder: (context, appState) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("TITLE"),
          ),
          body: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    Text(_state_var),
                    Center(
                      child: FlatButton(
                        child: Text('CHANGE VALUE'),
                        onPressed: () async {
                            _state_var = "SND TEST";
                            // OR
                            setState(() {
                              _state_var = "SND TEST";
                            });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ])
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Whats the difference between:

```
_state_var = "SND TEST";
```

and

```
setState(() {
    _state_var = "SND TEST";
});
```

I mean, in both cases the Text gets new value.

Comment: you should know how StatefulWidget works before using Redux https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html

Comment: and do not forget about `StatefulBuilder` - in most cases it is far more handy than boilerplate code using `StatefulWidget`